# S.M.A.R.T. error on the drive, how to deal with 80 bad sector?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

My system reported a S.M.A.R.T. error on the drive few days ago, Warning: Immediately back-up your data and replace your.

I backed up my data, and then tried to see what is the problem, using HDD regenerator 1.71 I found 80 bad sector at the first 5 Gigabyte of my drive ( 640 GB ), but when I choose scan an repair once it reach the 1st bad sector after 872 MB, the program stuck and regenerating ... and counting all sectors as bad sectors !

Is there a way to fix these sectors ? I'm having another windows at the last 50 GB of my drive and it's working normally, can I just delete the 1st partition (Make the 1st 5 GB unallocated) ? [the 1st partition is 50 GB and the windows on it is working good but slow and delays]

Comment: Once a sector is marked as bad its not possible mark them as good, not that you would want to do that, they are mark as being bad for a reason.  Its time to clone the hdd if you can ( set the software to ignore all errors ) and replace the hdd.  It might be working today but eventually it WILL STOP working once that happens nothing can be done.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1218312/pending-sector-issue-does-this-mean-the-hdd-is-failing/1218317#1218317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any software methods to regenerate this bad blocks.

You can cut out a bad parts of your hdd by creating partitions only in working areas (non Bad).